# Convert Inline C Assembler (Intel syntax to AT&T)

Tags: c++, assembly, x86

I am trying to convert this function from MSVC++ to MINGW (this is the original MSVC function)

```
    VOID __declspec(naked) BNSTUB()
{
   __asm
   {
      pushad;
      call OnChatPacketReceived;
      TEST EAX,EAX;

      popad;
      jnz oldCall;

        MOV EAX,0;
      MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+0x6FF3EBA0],1
      ret;
oldCall:
        CALL eax;
        MOV DWORD PTR DS:[EBX+0x6FF3EBA0],1
        ret;

   }
}
```

But I have problems with pushad and popad. they give me a "undeclared identifier"

Answer (score 2):

pusha
popa
(without the d)

Comment: Aren't those just the 16-bit (word) versions?

Answer (score 0):

In Mingw it might be called "pushall" instead of "pusha": so try "pushalld" and "popalld".

Comment: Actually, it's pushal and popal (without the extra 'l')

Answer (score 0):

You can compile something in C and also keep the assembler listing with `-S` parameter. That should display the AT&T syntax in all its glory.

Comment: The code which the compiler emits won't necessarily include an instance of the push-all-registers opcode, however.